# PyCharm Django ORM does not display Manager autocomplete children from django.db.models

Tags: python, django, orm, autocomplete, pycharm

So I'm frustrated by the autocomplete of Django PyCharm. It does not improved SQL completion and other enhancements.

```
from django.db import models
```

import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) < self.pub_date <= now
        #return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.choice_text
```

for example if I try using Question object from the model and look for objects (Question.objects) and typing dot after objects it should give me the suggestions of "all, first, last, etc." but it does not have any suggestions. It's hard to learn without it, any suggestions how could I fix this? 
I have installed latest interpreters like IPython, SQLAlchemy and more.
In addition to that I have "Collect run-time types information for code insight" enabled.

Comment: are you using the pro or the community edition of pycharm? only the pro has complete support for django.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly PyCharm has had this issue for a very long time and is likely never going to fix it.

I find myself having to do

`""":type varname: ObjectType"""`

or using `isinstance(..)`

to get autocomplete to work well.

Comment: Have you got a suggestion of an IDE that would do that? Trying to learn syntaxes fast but this just slows me down..

Comment: spyder might... but no; i still love PyCharm. the django docs are great for the times auto complete isn't working as well.